# Search users and sort by most number of mutual friends in Redis?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, redis

I have a potential database of 5 million users, where each user has a certain number of friends. What I need to do is implement search, such that users can filters by certain attributes (i.e. other user's gender etc), that part is fairly straightforward.

> User A searches for all Males and gets result set. User B, User C, User D

However, the user should also have the option to sort search results by the number of mutual friends that User A has with all the users in the result set

> Assuming
>      User A AND User B = 3 Mutual Friends
>      User A AND User C = 8 Mutual Friends
>      User A AND User D = 5 Mutual Friends

Then, the search should sort the results in following order

> User C, User D, User A

On top of that, since the results will be displayed on a webpage, I need support for pagination as well, so that all 5 million or so entries aren't processed each time user navigates between search results.

The web code is being written in C#, but in terms of database I'm pretty open and can go with SQL, NoSQL or Redis. Main priority is high-performance so Redis seems like a good option. How do I implement such a search requirement from datastore and pseudo-code point of view?

Answer (score 1):

In redis, you'd probably want to store this in a `zset`; there's no inbuilt automatic indexing in reds, so you'd need to `zadd` or `zincrby` when you add or remove friends (`zincrby` with a negative number to subtract). Then you'd just `zrange` or `zrangebyscore` to query it. These methods are all available under the `SortedSet` prefix in the `StackExchange.Redis` package on NuGet.

Comment: By "store this in a zset", do you mean store each user profile or mutual friends? If mutual friends, then wouldn't this create N x N sets, which for 5 mil will be 5 trillion sets. Can you please elaborate on your approach a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

My two cents.

You could take advantage of ZINTERSTORE if you maintain the gender index as a Set, and the mutual friends count as a SortedSet for each user (the score is the mutual friends count).
Also you'll need a set of friends per user.

For gender use a Set with the key format: `gender:{gender}` and each item will be a user id.

For friends use a Set with the key format: `friends:{userId}` and each item will be a user id.

For mutual friends use a SortedSet with the key format: `mutual:{userId}`, each item will be a user id and the score will be the number of common friends.

So, when adding a user you do:

```
void AddUser(string user, string gender)
{
    // Add to a gender set  "gender:{gender}"->{users}
    db.SetAdd($"gender:{gender}", user);
}
```

To add a friendship between two users:

```
void AddFriendship(string user1, string user2)
{
    // All friends of user1, should increment its mutual count with user2
    var user1Friends = db.SetMembers($"friends:{user1}");
    foreach(var user1Friend in user1Friends)
    {
        db.SortedSetIncrement($"mutual:{user1Friend}", user2, 1);
        db.SortedSetIncrement($"mutual:{user2}", user1Friend, 1);
    }

    // All friends of user2, should increment its mutual count with user1
    var user2Friends = db.SetMembers($"friends:{user2}");
    foreach (var user2Friend in user2Friends)
    {
        db.SortedSetIncrement($"mutual:{user2Friend}", user1, 1);
        db.SortedSetIncrement($"mutual:{user1}", user2Friend, 1);
    }

    // Add to friend sets   "friends:{user}->{users}"
    db.SetAdd($"friends:{user1}", user2);
    db.SetAdd($"friends:{user2}", user1);
}
```

And to get the users by gender ordered by mutual friend count:

```
static IEnumerable<string> GetUsersByGenderOrderByMutualFriends(string user, string gender)
{
    var db = mux.GetDatabase();
    var tempKey = "temp";
    db.SortedSetCombineAndStore(SetOperation.Intersect, tempKey, $"gender:{gender}", $"mutual:{user}", Aggregate.Sum);
    var result = db.SortedSetRangeByRank(tempKey, 0, -1, Order.Descending).Select(x => x.ToString());
    db.KeyDelete(tempKey);
    return result;
}
```